# Creating an array and obtaining the first value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database field named 'manufacturer' with some numbers separated by a pipe.

> e.g 1572|906|1573

I would like to select the first number and store it as a variable.

This is my woeful effort that has yielded no success.

```
$thisproductmansarray=array(); //declare the array

$thisproductmans=$myfield["manufacturer"]; //For page title / breadcrumb etc
$xxarray=implode("|", $thisproductmans[$key]);
foreach($thisproductmans as $key=>$val){ 
$thisproductmansarray[]=$xxarray++;
echo $thisproductmansarray[0];
}
```

Could anybody give me a pointer.
Thanks

Comment: Plenty of answers here, but here is another take on it...`substr( $string, 0, strpos( $string, '|' ) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xxarray=explode("|", $thisproductmans);
echo $xxarray[0]; // this should be what you want
```

Comment: implode() is wrong in this case. it would be correct if the data is hold in an existing array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = explode('|', $the-variable-where-the-data-is-in);
echo $data[0];
```

Will show the first number. In you example "1572".

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = explode("|", $fieldfromdb);
$val = $items[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = '1572|906|1573';
$first_num = current(explode("|",$str));
echo $first_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like explode is what you really want.  explode() takes a delimited string and converts to an array of parts.

```
$thisproductmans=$myfield["manufacturer"]; //For page title / breadcrumb etc
$xxarray=explode("|", $thisproductmans[$key]);
if(count($xxarray) > 1)
    echo $xxarray[0];
```

Check out the [man page](http://php.net/function.explode) for explode() if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first number directly without using an array:-

```
$var = "1572|906|1573";
list($first) = explode('|', $var);
```

`$first` will now = 1572.

[See](http://3v4l.org/lGJpF) it [working](http://3v4l.org/YUQbB) and [`list()`](http://php.net/list).

If you have PHP V >= 5.4 you can do this:-

```
$var = "1572|906|1573";
$first = explode('|', $var)[0];
var_dump($first);
```

[See it work](http://3v4l.org/fXtdu).

Answer (score -1):

An example for you to use it in your code

```
<?php
$var = "1572|906|1573";

$array1 = explode("|", $var);

$first_value = $array1[0];
echo $first_value;  // Output here is 1572

?>
```